# Github's Limiting Branches in a Single Push

Tags: git, github

Github has a beta feature to limit the number of branches and tags touched with each push. I notice it enforces a minimum of 2. Why not make it just 1? In a company's development flow, I don't see a reason of why you'd need to update more than 1 branch at a time - your feature branch or main if you have privileges.

Maybe it has to do with tags? I don't use tags in my development flow so that could be why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's to make merging/rebasing/picking between two branches easier (so you can update both heads locally but only need to push once). That being said, it would be legitimate for someone to create a bunch of branches locally and wait to push them until they have a network connection. It's a tradeoff of safety/security vs how often you'd want to push like that.